# SoapUI Conditional Goto - contains key word

Tags: conditional-statements, soapui

Is it possible to evaluate an error response from a load balancer to replay a previous step using a conditional goto? For example the request may come back as below:

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not possible to use namespace in the above example. Could anyone please advise if this is possible I.e. by searching a certain phrase in the message, without having to write a custom groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

A Groovy test step may be your only option. If you have assertions on your test step checking for valid responses, receiving a 502 or other error will short-circuit your test case and you won't get to the conditional step.

The following is a simple Groovy test step that looks for "502 Bad Gateway" anywhere in the response of the test step `SOAP Request` and executes the test step again:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "SOAP Request#Response" )

// Check for a 502 Bad Gateway error 
if (holder["//text()[contains(.,'502 Bad Gateway')]"]) {

     log.info('Got 502 error... retrying the test step')
 
    def testCase = testRunner.testCase
    def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("SOAP Request");
    testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
    testStep.run(testRunner, testStepContext);

} else {

    log.info('Running normal assertions...')
}
```

But, there's a bit of thinking that needs to go into retries: if you retry a request immediately you'll probably get the same response, so you'd likely need to build in a delay. And, how many times should you retry before giving up, and what about other error types? One advantage of using a Groovy test step is you can call on lots of Java libraries that handle retries, such as [Guava](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying).